# My Flutter App is not running after adding cloud_firebase package

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle

Recently I have added firebase to my flutter project. To use firebase database services I have added cloud_firebase package. But after adding this package my app is not running and giving me an exception:

```
BUILD FAILED in 31s
The plugin cloud_firestore requires a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to the file C:\Users\Jaguar\Desktop\AppDevelopment\acadmt\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
  }
}
Note that your app won't be available to users running Android SDKs below 19.
Alternatively, try to find a version of this plugin that supports these lower versions of the Android SDK.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**The exception message is also suggesting following suggestions**:

```
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

I have tried the first two suggestions but still, the app is not working.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It will work after changing the minSdkVersion to 21 at  project_folder/android/app/build.gradle.

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

**For the Projects Created After Flutter 2.8 Update**

1. Add this to `project_folder/android/local.properties`

   `flutter.minSdkVersion=21`
2. Now update your `project_folder/android/app/build.gradle`

   `defaultConfig { minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger() }`
3. Run `flutter clean && flutter pub get`
4. Rerun app

Reference: [Change Android Minsdkversion in Flutter  –  2 Easy Ways [2022]](https://www.flutterbeads.com/change-android-minsdkversion-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 4):

Previous Answers are also correct. I just used another approach.

1. First add `flutter.compileSdkVersion=21` in `local.properties` file.
2. Then add this code in `app\build.gradle`

```
def flutterMinSdkVersion = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion')
if (flutterMinSdkVersion == null) {
    flutterMinSdkVersion = '21'
}
```

3. After this make sure minSdkVersion is added to defaultConfig inside `app\build.gradle`

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion flutterMinSdkVersion.toInteger()
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
  }
}
```

Result:  Running with sound null safety

Answer (score 1):

This problem is happening because a package that you are using is not compatible with the new version of flutter

---

### Side note -> try not to upgrade flutter during working on an old project to avoid these problems

To solve it in flutter version 3.0.5 and after changing minSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion values place, you need to go to this path in your flutter sdk:

> "your_flutter_sdk/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

then update: minSdkVersion = 19 , compileSdkVersion = 31

```
 static int compileSdkVersion = 31 //compile sdk new version
 static int minSdkVersion= 19 //min sdk new version
 static int targetSdkVersion = 31 //target sdk new version = compile sdk version
```

- in terminal run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` then run your application

hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You may not apply changes after editing minSdkVersion

to solve this problem:

1-open build.gradle file and edit it:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
  }
}
```

then on right side of android studio,make sure to select **open for editing in android studio** to apply changes and syncing gradle for new changes.

2-make a clean **(File>invalidate Caches/Restart)**

Comment: After this I am still getting an error with following message:
[!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.
    To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
    To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Well. It worked after changing the version to 21 instead of 19.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these lines to build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    compileSdkVersion 33
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**paste this code in the project's local.properties file**

**path:** "android\local.properties"

```
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\**"your pc's name"**\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
flutter.targetSdkVersion=31
flutter.compileSdkVersion=31
flutter.versionCode=1
```

**replace the defaultConfig with this code in your build.gradle**

**path:** "android\app\build.gradle"

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.rentatouille"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
    targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Go to this path :

> C:\Users\Jaguar\Desktop\AppDevelopment\acadmt\android\app\build.gradle

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
  }
}
```

change your minSdkVersion to 30

that is:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 30
  }
}
```

Comment: it runs just fine with `minSdkVersion 21`, by changing it to 30 you are excluding a very big amount of android users